# Entity Framework Values not carrying across to code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

First I'll explain a tad exactly what is happening, most of my values from my database are fine when I execute a linq to grab them, but specific ones such as `ItemNumber` and `JobReference` don't seem to carry across to the code, so I can't compare them.

Here is my linq statement for getting all the items.

```
public List<PurchaseOrderItem> GetPurchaseOrderItems()
{
    return _context.PurchaseOrderItems.Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHeader).ToList();
}
```

Here is the statement for getting a specific item:

```
public PurchaseOrderItem GetPurchaseOrderItem(PurchaseOrderItem selectedPoLine)
{
    foreach (var item in GetPurchaseOrderItems())
        if (item.JobReference == selectedPoLine.JobReference && 
            item.ItemNumber == selectedPoLine.ItemNumber)
           return item;

        return null;
        //return _context.PurchaseOrderItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.JobReference == selectedPoLine.JobReference && p.ItemNumber == selectedPoLine.ItemNumber);
}
```

Here is my problem

[image: Screenshot of problem]

See how the `item.JobReference` is empty?

Well this doesn't make sense because if I check in my database, the value for the `JobReference` is there and is correct ...

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the setter of ``PurchaseOrderItem.JobReference``, and check for yourself what is happening. There could be some much stuff wrong.

Comment: Can you verify whether all `JobReference` values are coming empty, as opposed to just a few, aka something like `bool checking = _context.PurchaseOrderItems.Any(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.JobReference));`.

Comment: Could you show us your model and your mappings? And what is the sql statement executed?

Comment: All Job References are returning empty, for now i've had to revert changes, but still not sure what caused this.

Comment: ``what caused this.`` - you talking about the past, so the question is obsolete?

Comment: I've reverted my changes for now, as i have to push the application down to clients systems, the question still very much stands, as of now it's working.

Comment: I doubt you will get an answer of a problem thats not existing anymore. At least you could have shared all your changes you have made, and we could give a clue what could be the culprit, but with the amount of information you provided all we can do is wild guesses. Good luck.

Comment: Also, EF version and mapping information is required.